# I want to select branch id,branch location where sum of total item is greter than 11 in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
entire_collection[{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("571ca6076e589915f893ee8c"),    
    "cbill_details" : [
        {
            "c_branch_id" : "b25", 
            "c_branch_location" : "Kolkata", 
            "c_total_item" : NumberInt(5), 

        }, 
        {
            "c_branch_id" : "b27", 
            "c_branch_location" : "Kolkata", 
            "c_total_item" : NumberInt(7), 

        }, 
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("571ca6076e589915f893ee8f"),    
    "cbill_details" : [
        {
            "c_branch_id" : "b25", 
            "c_branch_location" : "Kolkata", 
            "c_item" : NumberInt(9), 

        }, 
        {
            "c_branch_id" : "b27", 
            "c_branch_location" : "Kolkata", 
            "c_item" : NumberInt(3), 

        }, 
    ]
}]
```

**group by "c_branch_id" and "c_branch_location" where the sum of "c_item">11 in mongodb**

here b25 in 1st document contains item= 5 and in 2nd document, item =9.so the b25 wise total item is (5+9)=14 and in case of b27 total item is 10. then after executing query the output will be b25 and its corresponding location.

Comment: Use MongoDB [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) with [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fistly you need aggregation query to match data for your question

and your query is like this

```
db.entire_collection.aggregate(
{$unwind : "$cbill_details"},
{$group : {"_id" : {"c_branch_id" : "$cbill_details.c_branch_id", 
                    "c_branch_location" : "$cbill_details.c_branch_location"},
                    "total_item" : {"$sum" : "$cbill_details.c_total_item" }}},
{$match : {"total_item" : {$gt : 11}}}
)
```

and your document is  a bit diffrent because your one field is `"c_total_item"`and another filed is `"c_item"`

and mongodb agregation documention link is here : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/